# How to install rn-fetch-blob

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I'm using RN 0.61.5 and did an installation using npm of rn-fetch-blob latest version. Their documentation says add pods if using Cocoapods which I did, would I need to do linking for the package? Since it is RN 0.6+, I know it is not required to run `react-native link`
and I also tried manual linking during which I get an error `'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found`. For that problem, I have also tried in Xcode updating Search Paths but that didn't work either. When I leave out linking, Blob build function doesn't work but the build succeeds. Does anyone have an idea of whether I need linking or not and how to do it? Their documentation is vague.

Comment: Did you use cocoa pods before installing fetch-blob?

Comment: Yes, pods were working fine.

Comment: And you opened the xcode works space instead of xcode project?

Comment: Yes, I have been working with lot of modules, so I tried common ways of fixing them. My question is do I need to link it or pods installation is enough?

Comment: Normally pods should be enough (based on my experience) due to the autolinking.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it?